# How to give a counter variable in a c-string to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, c-strings

I have a function in main which takes a string from main function.

In main I have the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
  char string[] = "string" ;

  function(string);

  return 0;
}
```

In this function I have a loop iterating over the string. When a specific condition is true I call another function which has to take the string again and also the counter.

```
unsigned int function(char* string)
{
  int counter = 0;
  while (string[counter] == ...)
  {
     if (... some condition ...) 
       anotherFunction(&string, &counter)
  }
}
```

function prototype of `anotherFunction()`:

```
anotherFunction(char* string[], int* counter)
```

The problem is how do I handle the string with the counter here in this function?

```
void anotherFunction(char* string[], int* counter)
{
  // ??? string[counter] // ???
}
```

Comment: this looks like pseudo code, do you have something that compiles to show us?

Comment: In `function`, don't pass to `anotherFunction` the address of the string (pointer to pointer), just pass the original string (pointer to char). Then use it in `anotherFunction` the same way you use it in `function`. The signature of `anotherFunction` should be `void anotherFunction(char *, int *)`.

Comment: It would be far easier to answer if this were real code and you explained what you need it to do.  Currently it is rather "theoretical" and appears to start from a flawed understanding of string parameters.  So answering your question directly will simply perpetuate that misunderstanding.  That is we can tell you how to access the string as-is, but it is unlikely that you need to do that if the function signature and calling were more plausible.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing both `string` and `counter` to `anotherFunction()` as a pointers, therefore to access a character in the string you need to de-reference both:

```
*string[*counter]
^       ^
```

However it is not at all clear why you are passing these arguments by pointer.  In the case of `string` it is almost certainly an error.  In the case of `counter` it is only necessary if `anotherFunction()` is to modify `counter` and for that modification to be visible in the calling function.

It seems likely that you intended *either*:

```
void anotherFunction( char* string, int* counter)
```

then

```
string[*counter]
```

or

```
void anotherFunction( char* string, int counter)
```

and

```
string[counter]
```

If you did want to modify `counter` it is better perhaps to simply return a value:

```
int anotherFunction( char* string, int counter);
```

Then:

```
counter = anotherFunction( string, counter ) ;
```